# MySQL Query only grabbing one row instead of multiple. Why?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to grab multiple rows via these lines from the MySQL database:

```
$msg_sql = "SELECT * FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."quotes ORDER BY rand(curdate()) LIMIT 3";
$msg_res = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link, $msg_sql));
print_r($msg_res);
```

However, I only get 1 row back. Which is:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [message] => test_message [Link] => link here )
```

I wish to get multiple rows (so multiple ID's)

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I'm still new to MySQL.

Comment: Not the reason you are getting only one row, but _do not_ call `mysqli_query()` inside `mysqli_fetch_*()`. Call it and store its resource in a variable, check for FALSE on that variable, then fetch.

Comment: Just curious as to why this is good practice? Thank you. Does it result in poor caching?

Comment: Calling the query inside the fetch makes it impossible to check for errors. And though it may work (without checking for errors) when _only one_ row is expected to return, it cannot be used at all when fetching multiple rows in a `while` loop, which is what you'll do most of the time, because it reruns the query on each loop iteration.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must loop once for each row you fetch.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $msg_sql);
while ($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r($item);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked perfectly. Sorry for being a noob at MySQL. People like you who are patient with the newbies are what makes this community so great! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through your results:

```
$results = mysqli_query($link, $msg_sql);
while ($msg_res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
{
    print_r($msg_res);
}
```

Comment: This will re-run the query every cycle of the loop.

Comment: You're calling the query on each loop iteration!

Comment: I was updating as you were voting. Please reconsider your vote.

Comment: It's still wrong, you don't need to pass the link to `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

Comment: well you got 10 sec faster, so no use keeping my answer :) have my vote